# QXmlSchema can not find linked files

Tags: xml, xsd, qt5

I have a question about the QXmlSchema. The base of the problem is a xml schema with exists out of three files --> The SCHEMA.xsd --> CompleyTypes.xsd and SimpleTypes.xsd

The SCHEMA.xsd includes the complexTypes.xsd this one includes the SimpleTypes.xsd.

I'm using QT5 and I load my schema as the following part of my code shows:

```
if(m_xml_shema.load(QUrl(QString("file://home/user/me/SCHEMA.xsd"))
{
   // The schema is correct!
}
```

My question is does the load function of the QXmlSchema also implement the linked .xsd files? If I try to validate, the validator says that I element which is defined in the complexTypes.xsd can not be found! All files are in the same directory, I also checked the names of the files and my XML Editor is able to find the linked files!

Where can the mistake be? 
Do I have to load the schema in a different way?
Di I have to load all three files?

Comment: Please post the XSDs.

Comment: I can not post the xsd. Is it in principle possible that the QT framework loads also the linked files , or do I have to load them seperate?

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention in the comments that you cannot post the XSDs, you should **create the simplest case that still exhibits the problem**.  I cannot tell you what QT does, but to answer your question in the comments:  Yes, it should be possible for it to locate the included or imported XSDs without you having to load them explicitly.  Xerces-based parsers would, in fact, do that.

Let me try to help you with a **simple case that shows the structure of your issue**:

**SCHEMA.xsd:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           version="1.0">
  <xs:include schemaLocation="ComplexTypes.xsd"/>
  <xs:element name="a" type="aType"/>
</xs:schema>
```

**ComplexTypes.xsd:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           version="1.0">
  <xs:include schemaLocation="SimpleTypes.xsd"/>
  <xs:complexType name="aType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="b" type="bType"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

**SimpleTypes.xsd:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           version="1.0">
  <xs:simpleType name="bType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
      <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
      <xs:maxInclusive value="1"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

**a.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<a xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="SCHEMA.xsd"><b>1</b></a>
```

**A Xerces-based parser will report that `a.xml` above is valid as-is, but invalid if you change the `1` to a `2`; it finds all of the needed XSDs fine.**  Note, however, that there are simple missteps made frequently regarding the specification of the XSD file names, directories, URLs, namespaces, etc.  That's why I suggested that you post your actual XSDs (or a pruned down version that still exhibits the problem).  I suggest that you try the above files to see if QT can find all of these XSDs.  If it can, then you'll know to focus on your particular use of the `xs:include` or `xs:import` statements.  Comment if you have any follow-ups.  Hope this helps.